# How to remove all files with a specific extension from version control?

Tags: bash, shell, version-control, mercurial

I am using **Mercurial** under **Linux**. I would like to exclude all files containing the pattern `*.pro.user*` from the version control system.

I tried to list all the files with:

```
find . -name "*.pro.user*"
```

This turned out also some results which are in the `.hg` folder:

```
...
./.hg/store/data/_test_run_multiple/_test_run_multiple.pro.user.i
./.hg/store/data/_test_non_dominated_sorting/_test_sorting.pro.user.i
./Analyzer/AlgorithmAnalyzer.pro.user
./Analyzer/AlgorithmAnalyzer.pro.user.a6874dd
...
```

I then tried to pipe this result to the *hg forget* command like:

```
find . -name "*.pro.user*" | hg forget
```

but I get:

```
abort: no files specified
```

My guess is that the list needs to be processed in some way in order to be passed to `hg forget`.

I would like to ask:

1. How can I pass the result of my find query into the `hg forget` command?
2. Since the query result contains files in the "private" folder `.hg`, is it a good idea? I hope that Mercurial will ignore that request, but shoud I remove those results somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
hg forget "set:**.pro.user*"
```

This tells Mercurial to forget any files that match the fileset `**.pro.user*`.  As the fileset is defined in Mercurial, it won't go into the `.hg` directory.  You can do even more with filesets by looking at: `hg -v help filesets`

The `**` at the start means to work in subdirectories, rather than just the current directory.

Comment: This is probably the best way to go.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can use `find * -name "*.pro.user*"` to avoid looking in `.hg`.

Mercurial's `forget` command requires its arguments on the command line. So you need to use `xargs`:

```
find * -name "*.pro.user*" | xargs hg forget
```

Alternatively you can ask `find` to do the job:

```
find * -name "*.pro.user*" -exec hg forget {} \;
```

Finally, you should add `*.pro.user*` to your `.hgignore` file.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the xargs! I tested both options and they both work!